# GCP Instance Connection Disruption

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, cloud, connection

I am a novice GCP user trying to run 4 scripts in parallel on an a linux instance with 4 CPUs, 4 GPUs, 15 GB RAM, and 30 GB Disk space.

However, a few minutes after initializing my scripts, both WinSCP and PuTTY disconnect me from the server and I am unable to reconnect. The instance appears to continue running on GCP website. I've tried making a new instance but the problem remains.

When I run just a single script on the instance, I have no issues.

Any idea what might be causing this? Any clues would be an enormous help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be OOM Killer killed sshd due to heavy load of your server while running 4 script in parallel.
You can monitor your VM load and check whether the time you got kicked form ssh is when the load spike.

You could try:
Restart the server, reconnect and check the log whether OOM Killer kick in.

Comment: You were right, I just needed to increase CPUs to 4 and RAM to 30GB. Thanks!